# pivoting array of object data javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i have an array of object like this:

```
const data =[{
    "username": "MT220047",
    "title": "Test",
    "position": "Management Trainee",
    "department": "Logistic",
    "2022-11-15": 1,
    "2022-11-16": 2
  },
  {
    "username": "MT220047",
    "title": "UntitledForm1",
    "position": "Management Trainee",
    "department": "Logistic",
    "2022-11-16": 1
  },
  {
    "username": "17000691",
    "title": "Test",
    "position": "Foreman",
    "department": "Production",
    "2022-11-16": 1,
    
  }
]

const date =["2022-11-11","2022-11-12","2022-11-13","2022-11-14","2022-11-15","2022-11-16"]

const accumulator = {}
const final =[]
const res = date.map((tanggal)=>{ return data.reduce((a,e)=>(a[e.tanggal]={...(a[e.tanggal] || {}), ...e}, a),{});})
       
console.log(res)
```

it try to get the summary or pivot value of the dates, but i get this result instead of what i expected:

```
[ { undefined:
     { username: '17000691',
       title: 'Test',
       position: 'Foreman',
       department: 'Production',
       '2022-11-15': 1,
       '2022-11-16': 1 } },
  { undefined:
     { username: '17000691',
       title: 'Test',
       position: 'Foreman',
       department: 'Production',
       '2022-11-15': 1,
       '2022-11-16': 1 } },
  { undefined:
     { username: '17000691',
       title: 'Test',
       position: 'Foreman',
       department: 'Production',
       '2022-11-15': 1,
       '2022-11-16': 1 } },
 ....]
```

my expected result should be like this:
i try to get the summary total of the dates base on the date array...

```
 summary_date:[ {"2022-11-15": 1},{"2022-11-16": 4}]
```

or is it possible to get this result:

```
data = [{"date":"2022-11-16","total":4},{"date":"2022-11-15","total":1}]
```

any help on this, or can someone tellme where did i do wrong here?

Comment: Can you refactor your map/reduce line with more descriptive names? Generally it’s really hard to help if we need to read very terse code. Also not sure why this is tagged as Java?

Comment: uhmm can you explains what did you mean by more descriptive....

Comment: i try to get the summary total of the dates base on the date array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of an outer `.reduce()` over the `data` array with an inner `.foreach()` over all the `dates` should do it:

```js
const data =[{
"username": "MT220047",
"title": "Test",
"position": "Management Trainee",
"department": "Logistic",
"2022-11-15": 1,
"2022-11-16": 2
  },
  {
"username": "MT220047",
"title": "UntitledForm1",
"position": "Management Trainee",
"department": "Logistic",
"2022-11-16": 1
  },
  {
"username": "17000691",
"title": "Test",
"position": "Foreman",
"department": "Production",
"2022-11-16": 1,

  }
]

const dates =["2022-11-11","2022-11-12","2022-11-13","2022-11-14","2022-11-15","2022-11-16"]

const res=data.reduce((ac,c)=>{
 const a=(ac[c.title]??={});
 dates.forEach(d=>{if(c[d]) a[d]=(a[d]??0)+c[d]});
 return ac;
}, {});

console.log(res);

// convert res into an array of objects resa:
const resa=Object.entries(res).reduce((a,[k,v])=>
 [...a,{title:k},...Object.entries(v).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}))], []);
console.log(resa);
```

The `.forEach()` callback function

```
d=>{if(c[d]) a[d]=(a[d]??0)+c[d]}
```

does the following:

1. For each date `d` it checks whether the current `data` element `c` has a property `d`
2. if so, the element `a[d]` of the accumulator object `a` is checked for existence and, if necessary, initialised to `0`
3. the value of `c[d]` is then added to `a[d]`

### Yet another update to the updated question:

```js
const data =[{
"username": "MT220047",
"title": "Test",
"position": "Management Trainee",
"department": "Logistic",
"2022-11-15": 1,
"2022-11-16": 2
  },
  {
"username": "MT220047",
"title": "UntitledForm1",
"position": "Management Trainee",
"department": "Logistic",
"2022-11-16": 1
  },
  {
"username": "17000691",
"title": "Test",
"position": "Foreman",
"department": "Production",
"2022-11-16": 1,

  }
]

const dates =["2022-11-11","2022-11-12","2022-11-13","2022-11-14","2022-11-15","2022-11-16"]

const res=Object.entries(data.reduce((a,c)=>{
 dates.forEach(d=>{if(c[d]) a[d]=(a[d]??0)+c[d]});
 return a;
}, {})).map(([date,total])=>({date,total}));

console.log(res);
```

Changing your question several times makes it unnecessarily hard for anyone to answer it. Please phrase any question you post here carefully and consider that others are investing their time and effort into preparing (and updating!) answers for you.

Comment: can you explained to me the function for the dates.forEach?...

Comment: i just update my question @CarstenMassmann

Comment: And I updated my answer. My `res` object looks slightly different from your expected `res` array. But in my view it makes more sense like that. You can, however, easily convert it to your format.

Comment: is it possible to set the result into array of object?

Comment: Yes: `resa` is now an array of objects. Exactly as specified in your question.

Comment: uhm sorry for bothering again, can i ask last question? @CarstenMassmann, if yes i have updated my question again...

Comment: You sent your comment before having updated the question. I got it now.

Comment: yes maybe can you take a look again on my latest update on my question..